# How can I authenticate JWT token for each request coming through SignalR hub?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a React application which is connected to SignalRHub on an ASP.net core app.
I configured application like that.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });


           ...
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {

                        string accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            (path.StartsWithSegments("/myHub")))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

I'm trying to achieve that

-User logs in with a username and password.

-I create a JWT token.

```
public User Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = _users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password);

            // return null if user not found
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            // authentication successful so generate jwt token
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            // remove password before returning
            user.Password = null;

            return user;
        }
```

-After that I create a SignalR connection from React side.
 have configured the authentication as shown.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/myHub", {
    accessTokenFactory: () => {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token;
    }
}).configureLogging(0).build();
```

and craeted Hub like that.

```
[Authorize]
public class MyHub: Hub
{    
    [Authorize]
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("MessageReceived", message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when it is trying to open a connection to SignalR hub, it uses JWT token as well. But after that, when it is calling hub methods, it doesn't check whether if JWT still valid or not.

What is the correct way of validating JWT token for each hub method call?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to this issue that wasn't possible at the time you posted the question.

It relies on creating middleware with the `IHubFilter` interface, which is available as of .NET 5.0.

The middleware will grab the `exp` claim value, check if it's expired, if not it will proceed to the function otherwise it will throw an exception which we will catch in the JavaScript client.

```
public class TokenFilter : IHubFilter
{
    public async ValueTask<object> InvokeMethodAsync(HubInvocationContext invocationContext, Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object>> next)
    {
        string expClaim = invocationContext.Context.User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "exp").Value;
        DateTime ExpiryTime = ExtensionMethods.UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Convert.ToDouble(expClaim));

        if (ExpiryTime < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            throw new HubException("Token Expired");
        }
        else
        {
            return await next(invocationContext);
        }
    }
}

// Helper to covert a Unix timestamp to a DateTime
public DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Reference the `TokenFilter` in your `AddSignalR` options and that's it for the server side.

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.AddFilter<TokenFilter>();
});
```

To catch the exception in JavaScript add `.catch` to your `.invoke('methodname')`, check for the message thrown and then respond accordingly

```
function errorHandler(err) {
    if (err.message.includes("Token Expired")) {
        console.log("The token has expired")
        // get new token or return to login or whatever you want to happen
    }
}

myHub.invoke('MethodName').catch(errorHandler);
```

As mentioned by @balazs it's worth adding `ValidateLifetime = true` and `ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero` because otherwise the user can create a new connection for 5 minutes after the token expires.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the ValidateLifetime = true in the TokenValidationParameters.
You can also add the ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero.

Comment: although I add ValidateLifetime = true , ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero, it is still able to request and get a successful response after expiration time,.

Comment: Did you try it with a non-SignalR endpoint?
Do you have UseAuthentication in the Startup.Configure before UseSignalR?

Comment: Hey, I also have this issue, did you ever work this out?

Comment: @CalDow the documentation on the microsoft page has been updated. It now states 
`The server validates the token and uses it to identify the user. This validation is done only when the connection is established. During the life of the connection, the server doesn't automatically revalidate to check for token revocation.`
According to statement above, It looks like its an expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do the check on the client side so you provide the opportunity to renew the token. Otherwise, you should be able to provide a [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1).